# DataGrid cell selected with text shadow style?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I am trying to add a text shadow to cell text when the row is selected.

**UPDATE:**

This is what I have now:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Setter Property="TextOptions.TextFormattingMode" Value="Display" />
    <Setter Property="RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint" Value="Enabled" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="CellContent" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="CellContent" Property="TextOptions.TextFormattingMode" Value="Display" />
                        <Setter TargetName="CellContent" Property="RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint" Value="Enabled" />
                        <Setter TargetName="CellContent" Property="Effect">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="2" BlurRadius="2" Color="Black" RenderingBias="Quality" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

It adds shadow to text only (just what I want) and when the row is selected (just what I want). The only problem is now that I am losing subpixel antialiasing:

[image]

The selected row is the one below with blueish background. It is now using some kind of gray antialiasing which make it look bad. I tried to set `RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint` without success. How do I enable it so that it looks as sharp and clear as the rows without selection?

This is how the gray antialiasing looks in 100% size (blurry):

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The background of the cell is preventing you from seeing the effect. Just set the background like this, but I don't know if you appreciate the result:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
  <Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
      <Setter Property="Effect">
        <Setter.Value>
          <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="2"
                            BlurRadius="2"
                            Color="Black"
                            RenderingBias="Quality"/>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Trigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

**Edit**

Maybe this is better because it gives you more control:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <ContentPresenter x:Name="CellContent"/>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="CellContent" Property="Effect">
              <Setter.Value>
                <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="2"
                                  BlurRadius="2"
                                  Color="Black"
                                  RenderingBias="Quality"/>
              </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
          </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I almost solved the problem, I have updated the question with more info and if I can get it to work I'll mark yours as an answer.

Comment: @rFactor First I think fonts are optimized for black and white but it could also have something to do with the style of the TextBox. Maybe you can derive from the TextBox control and create a boolean dependencyproperty with IsDropShadowEnabled and refer to it in the trigger of the ControlTemplate. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752068(v=vs.85).aspx for the style which is from the .NET Framework 3 (it's easier than the .NET 4 style) The part that needs the shadow is the `ScrollViewer` named PART_ContentHost.